# проблема с функцией gets()

Tags: c++, функции, testng

Из-за чего могут быть проблемы с функцией  gets() ?
Тестирующая система выдает такую ошибку:
Content-type: text/xml

45a5b2ff-e647-482e-b475-39768bf61a7e
  003839.cpp: In function 'int main()':
003839.cpp:17:16: error: 'gets' was not declared in this scope
   while (gets(s))
                ^

Так выглядит часть моего кода, где используется gets()

```
int main()
{    const char* sep = ".!?:-,;() \t\n";
      ifstream file;
      file.open("input.in");
      file.open("output.out");
  while (gets(s))
  {
    if (!s[0])
      break;
//
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Неплохо бы посмотреть весь код. Наверное, забыли нужный `#include` - `stdio.h` - или компилятор из свежайших, в котором эту функцию уже выбросили.

В любом случае, использовать `gets` крайне не рекомендуется. Замените на `gets_s`.

Comment: gets_s не обязателен для реализации. Замена gets - fgets.

Comment: вот весь код https://pastebin.com/tgrA4YG4, stdio.h был подключен

Comment: Это не тот код - по ссылке у вас `fgets`, а не `gets`! Вы случаем не Visual C++ 2015 или 2017 компилируете? Если заменить `fgets` на `gets` - да, эти компиляторы не компилируют - потому что `gets` из стандарта давно выброшен. А вот VC++ 2010 спокойно компилирует - предупреждая о небезопасности.

Comment: Я просто поменяла на gets. У меня dev c++, всё компилируется, но на информатиксе (тест. система) выдает ошибку

Answer (score 2):

Функция `gets` была удалена в стандарте C++14 из за ее крайней небезопасности. Она подвержена проблеме переполнения буфера, так как размер буфера в ней никак не указывается. Используйте `::std::string s` в качестве буфера и `file >> s` для чтения. Кроме того, после записи `file.open("output.out");` чтение будет производится из файла `output.txt`.

Comment: Не могли бы Вы проиллюстрировать на моем коде? Не очень понимаю, как интегрировать данную конструкцию

Comment: @JuliaPonomareva допустим `while(file >> s)` будет читать строки до конца файла

Comment: @VTT gets и `file >> s` не эквивалентны. Лучше использовать getline